# Absolute * Conditional = Doesn't converge?

Tags: calculus

Is there any example of 2 functions:
$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ - absolutely convergent,
$\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$ - conditionally convergent, but
$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx$ doesn't converge.

Comment: Take for instance $f=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $g=x$ in $(-\infty,\infty)$. Pretty sure there are simpler examples.

Comment: I meant to integrate it in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. With all integrals going from $1$ to $\infty$, take
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \begin{cases}
k^2, &\text{if $k\le x\le k+\frac1{k^4}$ for some even integer $k$}, \\
0, &\text{otherwise};
\end{cases} \\
g(x) &= \begin{cases}
(-1)^k k^2, &\text{if $k\le x\le k+\frac1{k^4}$ for some integer $k$}, \\
0, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}